# iPhone 5 Delete Unread Mail

Tags: iphone

Even though my inbox shows no mail, there is a note at the bottom of the screen that shows "787 Unread".   How can I clear or delete that note?

Answer (score 1):

There is an Unread smart tab on the main screen of the Mail app (if you can not see this, try going into edit and adding it). This will show you any downloaded emails that have not been read. From here you can mark all as read.